# How to know alignment requirements for a coroutine allocator?

Tags: c++, new-operator, coroutine

I would like to write a stack-like organized allocator for coroutines, but I cannot find how the memory is to be aligned. It seems that I can only query the alignment of the promise type.
Is that sufficient? (I guess not)
Or does a (helper) function/type exist that provides the alignment?
Or does a guarantee exist that it aligns as a specific primitive type?

Comment: `alignof(std::maxalign_t)` should be fairly safe.

Comment: std::max_align_t (with underscore between max and align)